# How to find masses when given tension?

Tags: physics

I don't understand how the following problem can be solved. There's not enough info.

[image]

This is what the book says about it, but it fails to explain how disc D is 1.0 kg:

[image]

Comment: Draw the free body diagram on D. You should find that $T_3$ balances the gravitational force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensions are caused, as you go up the cord, by the incresing number of disks.

If the masses are $a,b,c,d$, then you have 
$$
(a+b+c+d)g=98N,\ (b+c+d)g=58.8N,\ (c+d)g=49N,\ dg=9.8N.
$$
Now you can solve the last equation to find $d$, then the previous one to find $c$, and so on.